# Does Ubuntu multiboot effect windows?

Tags: windows

I have Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 PRO installed. Both no threats. I checked. But windows is taking a long time to turn off.  I restarted windiws but it has been on " Restarting " for 20+ mins. But I have to stare at [image: this]
Could this be from the multiboot. I scanned my windows with hit man PRO. AVAST 360 security  malware bytes. But Ubuntu never does this. It is slow at games so I us windows. Ubuntu I use for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Ubuntu doesn't affect Windows operations.  You do have access to the Windows partition as far as the browsing and manually accessing the files.  But that is very similar to browsing files on a network drive.

Ubuntu doesn't use any part of the Windows partition for its operation.

If you experience something particular regarding Windows, you would have to address VIA running Windows and the Windows environment, using a Windows support channel.  You might also leave out the part about running Ubuntu, it could distract from the real issue since it's completely separate and doesn't affect the actual running of Windows.

If, in the process of upgrading, or repairing Windows, you loose the Grub.  You may have to reinstall Grub.  The Boot Manager, is incidental, and doesn't affect the actual running of the Operation system.  Just how it's started.

Comment: So it is still doing it. Can I hold the button or can that break anything. ( if I have to remove windows, steam cloud saves). Also the reason is on Ubuntu Firefox frooz and so did my hole pc,  I waited nothing so I forced it off then turned it on and then tried to logg in but is just proght me back to the login screen, shutdown buttons where gone.

Comment: If it's locked up there isn't anything else you could do.  Performing a hard reboot would only affect the open files on the Operating system that is running.  I would perform a safe shutdown when possible.  But 5 minutes without activity, usually indicates a safe shutdown isn't possible.

Comment: The wheels is spilling and my hard drive in use light flashes every 5 seconds and turns off.

Comment: Tapping the power button once (sending a shutdown signal) should interrupt what it's doing and cancel what is locked up.  If it doesn't respond within a reasonable time (5 minutes would be a long time to wait).  That in an indication that it's locked up.  There isn't anything else you can do.